# strcpying a char* into a struct causes EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: c, xcode

I am trying to prototype a window manager thing and in my window struct there is a char* and I am trying to strcpy my variable for the window title into the char* member in my struct but I keep getting an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error and I have no idea how to fix it.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct window {
    char* title;
    int x;
    int y;
    int w;
    int h;
    void (*drawFunc)(struct window);
};

struct button {
    
};

void* draw(struct window w) {
    printf("hey");
    return (void*)0;
}

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
    struct window w;
    char* title = "hello\0";
    strcpy(w.title, title);
    w.drawFunc = draw(w);
    w.x = 10;
    w.y = 10;
    w.w = 100;
    w.h = 200;
    w.drawFunc(w);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `w.title` is an uninitialized pointer. It has no deterministic value, and whatever value it _does_ have almost certainly does not point to memory you can write to.

Comment: Also `w.drawFunc = draw(w);` is assigning `w.drawFunc` to the **return value** of `draw(w)` which is NULL. So you cannot invoke it with `w.drawFunc(...)` (you need a valid function pointer to call it).

Comment: Literal strings include the null-terminator automatically. You don't need to explicitly add it.

Comment: Also instead of `return (void*)0;` just `return NULL;`. If that's what it's supposed to return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's fixed code with comment explanations:

```
int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
    struct window w;
    char* title = "hello"; // "" adds \0 at the end automatically 
    w.title = strdup(title); // initialize pointer! needs memory allocation!
    w.drawFunc = draw; // assign function pointer, not function call return value
    ...
```

---

Note: `strdup` is a POSIX standard function,and  not in C standard, so you may meed to provide your own implementation, which is trivial:

```
char *strdup(const char *source) {
    char *result = malloc(strlen(source)+1);
    if(result) strcpy(result, source);
    return result;
}
```